# Accumulator used in Spark Listener results in inaccurate value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I'm trying to use Accumulators inside a ***SparkListener*** to record the number of records processed inside a ***DataFrame*** that was created from a Spark SQL Query.

After that, if I try to create a ***Dataframe*** via SQL Query, it returns the correct amount of records inside the ***DataFrame***. However, when I tried to rerun it several times, the value inside the accumulator is incorrect.

The code is shown below:

Attaching a Listener In SparkContext:

```
_sparkContext.addSparkListener(new SparkListener() { 
    override def onTaskEnd(taskEnd: SparkListenerTaskEnd) {

          OutputLogger.incrementRecord(taskEnd) 

      }
    })
```

Code for Incrementing Accumulator:

```
  private var recordAccumulator = ContextHelper.getSparkContext.accumulator(0, "Record Count")
  private var stageAccumulator = ContextHelper.getSparkContext().accumulator(0, "Stage Id")

def incrementRecord(taskEnd:SparkListenerTaskEnd) = {

      if(taskEnd.taskInfo.accumulables.size > 0 && taskEnd.taskType.toLowerCase().contains("shuffle")){
        val extractedValue = taskEnd.taskMetrics.shuffleWriteMetrics.get.shuffleRecordsWritten.toInt
        if(stageAccumulator.value == taskEnd.stageId.toInt){
          recordAccumulator += extractedValue
        }
        else{
          stageAccumulator.setValue(taskEnd.stageId.toInt)
          recordAccumulator.setValue(extractedValue)
        }
      }
  }


hiveContext.sql("select * from (select *, 'a' d from tempo_one union all select * from tempo_one join ( select 'b' d) a union all select * from tempo_one join ( select 'b' d) a union all select * from tempo_one join ( select 'b' d) a) b ").registerTempTable("df1") // 180 records
```

Code for executing SQL Queries:

```
val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sparkContext)
hiveContext.sql("select * from df1 where d = 'b'").registerTempTable("df2") //135 records

hiveContext.sql("select * from df1 where d = 'a'").registerTempTable("df3") //45 records

recordAccumulator.value //Value should be 45 however, it sometimes results to 34.
```

I ran this in local mode and the spark version is **1.6.0**

Any leads or reason on why the accumulator value is helpful.

Thank you.